# Android development - Java: How can i make byte array from File and back

Tags: java, android, arrays, file, byte

I am working on a small project, it should be something like remote file explorer via bluetooth.

I have this File:

```
File directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

I need to make a byte array from this File to send it to the second phone.

Can anybody please write me the code? Thanks and sorry for my english :)

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you have any sort of packages to do Bluetooth IO imported into your Java file?

Comment: can someone write my code is not a good approach for asking questions, before you ask a question you must have tried and also failed at do the task itself, and you should post what you have tried and how it failed.

Answer (score 1):

```
FileInputStream fis = new ....;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int readBytes = 0;
        while(readBytes != -1)
        {
            readBytes = fis.read(buffer);
            if(readBytes > 0)
            {
                bos.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
            }
            else 
                break;
        }
        byte[] fileData = bos.toByteArray();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: down vote accept
 

FileInputStream fis = new ....;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int readBytes = 0;
        while(readBytes != -1)
        {
            readBytes = fis.read(buffer);
            if(readBytes > 0)
            {
                bos.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
            }
            else 
                break;
        }
        byte[] fileData = bos.toByteArray();

Hope it helps

Comment: This doesn't work, i need to make byte array of directory not the concrete file. Here is the error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard (Is a directory)

Comment: A directory is logical structure with no physical existence. It can contain one or more files or directories. To create byte array for all files in a directory you need to do it for individual files in a directory. Look at java docs for file http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html on how it can be done. Also do give a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html. I believe this is what you want ...